# Fastest way to match two list fields python

Tags: python

I have an issue with time in my latest python script.
In essence, i have two lists, e.g.
List1:
`([a,1],[b,2])`
List2:
`([a,3],[b,4])`

Now in the example above i have provided two entries in each list. However, in reality there is about 150,000.

In my current script I retrieve the first field from the first list `[a]` and loop through the entire List2 till there is a match. The two list entries are then appended.

The final result would be:
`([a,1,3],[b,2,4])`

However, given the size of the lists this is taking forever.

Is there a way i can use the field of list1 `[a]` and in constant time retrieve all entries in list2 that have `[a]`

I have seen some answers online suggesting sets, but i am unsure as to how to implement one and use it to solve the solution above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Further example:

`l1=(['abc123','hi'], ['efg456','bye'])` - l1 has around 2000 tuples

`l2=(['abc123','letter'],['abc123','john'],['abc123','leaf'])` - l2 has around 100,000+ tuples

Output:
`l3=(['abc123','hi','letter'],['abc123','hi','john'],['abc123','hi','leaf'])`

Comment: Your examples are tuples of lists, not lists. Would you like to clarify that? Also is order important? Because lists (and tuples) are ordered but sets are not.

Comment: @YangHG You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @nick list1 has unique values, list2 has duplicates. Each field 'a' in list1 represents a parent function. Multiple tuples from list2 can reference that parent function. selcuk order is not important. Yang HG i will take a look at dict thanks

Comment: @Kingswoop If the list2 has duplicates, you couldn't convert it directly, please use Nick 's answer.

Comment: @YangHG Okay thanks, i will try now

Comment: @YangHG my answer won't work if list2 has duplicates

Comment: @Nick Sorry my mistake, I just saw you create a list as values, didn't consider details. You could easily use a for loop for list2

Comment: @YangHG I suspect that wouldn't be any faster than what OP currently has. I'm waiting for clarification of what the expected output is for duplicates to see if the answer can be modified, otherwise will delete.

Comment: I have added an second example, let me now if this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so hard, just use a dict for list1 and a for loop for list2.

```
dict1 = {key1: [value1] for key1, value1 in list1}  # convert list1 to dict
                                                    # and the values should be converted to dict
for key2, value2 in list2:
    try:
        dict1[key2].append(value2)
    except KeyError:
        continue  # I'm not sure what do you want to do if the keys in list2 didn't exist in list1, so just ignore them
list3 = tuple([key3, *value3] for key3, value3 in dict1.items())
print(list3)
```

Comment: Hi @YangHG , i have added another example at the bottom of my question. Does the above answer you gave still suit that problem?

Comment: Remembering that i currently loop through both lists and match on the key 'abc123' then append, then append into l3. However this is very slow as i have 100,000+ tuples in l2 and around 2000 in l1

Comment: @Kingswoop Of course yes. Your algorithm is O(m*n), but this algorithm is O(m+n). In my machine, I test list2 has 150000 items, it takes 60ms, then I test list2 has 1000000 items, it takes 400ms. list1 far less than list2, so it has little impact on Performance. Only one thing you need to take care, if list1 and list2 become too large, memory may overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If your `a` and `b` values are unique, you can convert the "lists" (what you have is actually a tuple of lists, not a list of lists) into dictionaries and then merge them. For example:

```
l1 = (['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 5])
l2 = (['a', 3], ['b', 4])

d1 = { k : [v] for [k, v] in l1 }
d2 = { k : [v] for [k, v] in l2 }

for k in d1.keys():
    d1[k] += d2.get(k, [])
    
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [5]}
```

You can convert that dictionary back to a tuple of lists using a comprehension:

```
print(tuple([k, *v] for k, v in d1.items()))
```

Output:

```
(['a', 1, 3], ['b', 2, 4], ['c', 5])
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks i will give this a go. l2 are not unique however, will this cause issues?

Comment: @Kingswoop this won't work if `l2` is not unique. Can you expand your question with some more representative data?

Comment: @Kingswoop for example, what is your expected output if there are two entries in `l2` with `a` e.g. `l2 = (['a', 3], ['b', 4], ['a', 6])`